# Clear error message (jquery) on input field focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, focus

```
function customAlert(inputID,msg){
   var div = $(".errorPopup");
   div.css({"display":"block"});
   $("#"+inputID).addClass("CO_form_alert").parent().addClass("alertRed");
   if (div.length == 0) {
     div = $("<div class='ErrorPopup' onclick='$(this).hide();'></div>");
     $("body").prepend(div);
   } 
   div.html(msg)
}
```

I am using the above jquery to hijack my form's javascript validation and error handling. It's working well, except I need to clear the error messaging and styling once the user clicks back into the field to correct it.

EDIT:

based on answers below, got it working - but I need to remove the focus on the field for IE (it already does this in firefox) -

```
<!--Jquery function to override JS alert with DOM layer alert message-->
function customAlert(){
    var args = arguments;
    if(args.length > 1) {
        // check that custom alert was called with at least two arguments
        var msg = args[0];
        $("li").removeClass("alertRed");
        $("input").removeClass("CO_form_alert");
        $("select").removeClass("CO_form_alert");
        var div = $(".errorPopup");
        div.css({"display":"block"});
        if (div.length == 0) {
            div = $("<div class='errorPopup' onclick='$(this).hide();'></div>");
            $("body").prepend(div);
        }
        div.html(msg);
        for(var i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
            var inputID = args[i];
           $("#"+inputID).addClass("CO_form_alert").parent().addClass("alertRed");
            $("#"+inputID).focus(function(){
                $(this).unbind('focus'); // remove this handler
                $('.errorPopup').hide(); // hide error popup

            });
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function customAlert(inputID,msg){
   var div = $(".errorPopup");
   div.css({"display":"block"});
   $("#"+inputID).addClass("CO_form_alert").parent().addClass("alertRed");
   if (div.length == 0) {
     div = $("<div class='errorPopup' onclick='$(this).hide();'></div>");
     $("body").prepend(div);
   } 
   div.html(msg);

   $("#"+inputID).focus(function(){
        $(this).unbind('focus'); // remove this handler
        $(this).removeClass("CO_form_alert")
               .parent().removeClass("alertRed"); // undo changes
        $('.errorPopup').hide(); // hide error popup
   });

}
```

Comment: @Jason -- you had 2 different names for `errorPopup` (one being `ErrorPopup` and the other `errorPopup`) -- i made it consistent, and it should now work

Comment: added: $('.ErrorPopup').hide(); div.css({"display":"none"});

Comment: @Jason don't use `div` make the changes as stated in my previous comment, it should work :-)

Comment: i should really use this @ stuff shouldent I @Neil :P

Comment: @John its ok. it usually only happens when i say my name out loud, not when it is clearly written there :-P

Comment: @Neal - trying to edit this to remove focus in IE from the field  - Works in firefox, but in IE the focus stays in the field. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Neal - would you mind elaborating - I've tried it various ways above, and I can't get blur to work properly

Answer (score 2):

```
$(":input").keypress(function(event) {
    $(".ErrorPopup").html("");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hide the error popup div on the input's focus event:

```
$('#' + inputID).focus(function() { $('.ErrorPopup').hide(); });
```